# Scrape a site with curl/wget appending a parameter to each site

Tags: http, wget, curl, string

I need to scrape a website for all sites and append an Paramater, e.g.

```
www.theSite.com/allpages?myPara=us
```

Now what I got is wget --recursive to get all sites, but that doesn't append the parameter and the content is useless. I need to do this in a 2nd step:

```
curl http://theSite.com/allpages?myPara=us | grep -c MyString
```

So in essence I am looking for a particular String in a entire Website to which I got only access via HTTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed now by using brackets and curl like this:

```
curl http://www.mySite.com/category1/category2/{+cat1,+cat2,+cat3,+cat4,+cat4}?myPara=us | grep -c myString
```

Of course this won't get me all sites, but one could work out a script with wget, regex, collections and loops.